# How to combine requests in to an array in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to combine two responses in to an array in angular?

Following is making an http post requests to two endpoints. How can I combine both of them an provide a return value as an array?

Like this:

```
postCombined() {
    return combineLatest([this.link1$, this.link2$])
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(([link1, link2]: [string, string]) => {
         return [
           this.http.post(link1, values1, { headers }),
           this.http.post(link2, values2, { headers }),
         ];
        })
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Is my implementation is correct? or do I need to use forkJoin?

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` seems the better option as it allows us to group multiple observables and execute them in parallel, then return only one observable.

`mergeMap` maintains multiple active inner subscriptions at once, so it’s possible to create a memory leak through long-lived inner subscriptions.

```js
postCombined() {
  return combineLatest([this.link1$, this.link2$])
    .pipe(
      let http1$ = this.http.post(link1, values1, {
        headers
      }), http2$ = this.http.post(link2, values2, {
        headers
      })
      forkJoin([https1$, http2$])
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Taken from [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handle-multiple-api-requests-in-angular-using-mergemap-and-forkjoin-to-avoid-nested-subscriptions-a20fb5040d0c)